# Returning Dictionary using webservice

Tags: dictionary, c#-3.0, streamreader

I'm looking for a bit of help with populating a Dictionary using a csv file within a WebService however Im unable to return the results.

Im tring to seperate the dictionary into two seperate columns which seemingly works but I cannot return the values as there are two and not one.

Here is the code:

```
{
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("T:/4 Year WBL/Applications Development/Coursework 2/2b/Coursework2bwebservice/abrev.csv");

    [WebMethod]
    public string Dictionary()
    {
        string  line;
       Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
       while ((line =  streamReader.ReadLine()) !=null)
       {
       string[] columns = line.Split(','); 
       dictionary.Add(columns[0], columns[1]);

       return dictionary;    
       }
    }
```

I am getting the error "cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string to string>"`

Any ideas would be great and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Dictionary()
```

is returning the wrong signature.  You need to return an actual dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary()
```

Also, this

```
while ((line =  streamReader.ReadLine()) !=null)
```

seems a bit hinky.  You're also returning your `dictionary` inside the loop.  Let's try instead:

```
line = streamReader.Readline();
while (line !=null)
{
   string[] columns = line.Split(','); 
   dictionary.Add(columns[0], columns[1]);
   line = streamReader.Readline();
}
return dictionary;
```

All that said, returning an actual dictionary object in a web method probably doesn't make much sense.  What you really want is an XML-serialized dictionary or list.  See here: https://www.google.com/search?q=return+dictionary+in+web+method for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, That is extremely helpful and resolves. Although as you say not properly as the webservice doesnt accept the dictionary class. I'll look into the serialized xml dictionary and start there. Thank you again.